# addView removeView clear OnClickListeners to prevent Memory Leak?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, onclicklistener

I have a framelayout with a button that programmatically inflates a view, add listeners to buttons in the created view and adds the view to the framelayout.

```
final View move = inflater.inflate(R.layout.overlay_move, null, false);
move.findViewById(R.id.overlay_move_left).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
...
frameLayout.addView(move, params);
```

One of the button in the created view is a close button which removes the view from the framelayout.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
frameLayout.removeView(move);
}
```

Do i need to clear the OnClickListeners before calling "removeView" to prevent memory leaks? Or will removeView do everything for me?

Comment: Clean up should be handled for your by the viewgroup, assuming you aren't holding a strong reference to the view you are removing.

Comment: As you can see in my code, I'm using no viewgroup for inflating my view. Do i need to do manual cleanup of listeners in this case?

Comment: Any view that contains another view is a viewgroup - so a FrameLayout would be a view group.  So, no, in your senerio I don't think there is any danger of a leak.